# What is different between these two loops in python 3.x?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
x = len(pdklist)
while x >= 0:
    if pdklist[-1].f in errorlist:
        pdklist.remove(pdklist[-1])
    x -= 1
```

The while loop does what I want. The for loop only removes
every other item in the list. It does print every item.f value though.
I originally did it this way and saw it was not right but have not been able to figure out why.

```
for item in pdklist:
    if item.f in errorlist:
        print(item.f)
        pdklist.remove(item)
```

Any help appreciated. Probably obvious once someone points it out but I don't see it.

Note: added information that the for loop prints all items but only removes half of them.

Comment: They do different things. The former is decidedly un-Pythonic whereas the other suffers from a different problem: you can't remove stuff from the list you are iterating over.

Comment: Ahh...did not know that. Yet, it DOES remove every other one. Why would it do that if it is not supposed to remove any?

Comment: It's one of several possible ill-defined outcomes.

Comment: Can you point me to anything that discusses why? My guess from reading other comments is that python keeps an internal pointer to each index number (similar to if I had done ...for i in range(len(pdklist)): and then del or remove by index number. Every time an item gets deleted, the index number changes and things get out of whack.

But that is a guess. Is it documented anywhere for me to read about it? Don't go to any trouble looking for it though. Just if you know off hand.

Comment: There's a large number of duplicates for this question; some of them have a more in-depth discussion. But yeah, pretty much like you surmise.

Comment: Quick googling brings up https://www.quora.com/In-Python-why-cant-you-remove-elements-from-a-list-with-a-for-loop-but-you-can-with-a-while-loop